# inequality/ measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

I have the following inequality:
$$\mu(\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}) = \int_X 1_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}}d\mu \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^p}\int_X 1_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}} \cdot |f_n-f_m|^p d\mu .$$
How do I get to the right side?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x\in X$ is such that  $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|>\epsilon$, then
$$1_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}}(x)=1<\left(\frac{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|}{\epsilon}\right)^p=1_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}}(x)\frac{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^p}{\epsilon^p}.$$
On the other hand, if $x\in X$ is such that  $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq \epsilon$ then
$$1_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}}(x)=0=1_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}}(x)\frac{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^p}{\epsilon^p}.$$
Hence, in any case, for $x\in X$,
$$1_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}}(x)\leq 1_{\{|f_n-f_m|>\epsilon\}}(x)\frac{|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^p}{\epsilon^p}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much Robert Z.:) I appreciate your help:)